# Update RecycleView particular position from Activity's startOnActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I would like to update a view of particular position of RecylerView but it does not happen due to some problem which are as follows-
1) when scroll up/down it created mess
2) I handle this by `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` but when scroll up/down then again it does not show previously saved child state.

My code are as follows-

ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class EventNameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventNameAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<EventNameModel> eventNameList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView eventNameText;
    public ImageView    imageViewRadio;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        eventNameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventNameText);
        imageViewRadio = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRadio);
    }
}


public EventNameAdapter(List<EventNameModel> eventNameList) {
    this.eventNameList = eventNameList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.event_name, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    EventNameModel movie = eventNameList.get(position);
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.eventNameText.setText(movie.getEventName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventNameList.size();
}
```

}

UPDATE POSITION CODE

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            int responseInt =   data.getIntExtra("SUBMIT_DATA",-2);
            Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this,"Response- "+responseInt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(responseInt>=0){
                    EventNameAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder = (EventNameAdapter.MyViewHolder) nameRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(responseInt);
                    if (viewHolder != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this,"Response 2 - "+responseInt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.imageViewRadio.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_button_on);
                            Log.d("hellotom", "if i=" + responseInt);

                    } else {
                        Log.d("hellotom", "else i=" + responseInt);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me how I will solve this issue.

Comment: How about updating via the recyclerview adapter instead of directly editing the viewholder yourself?

Comment: I would like to update only the particular position child but it's depend on previous activity's response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `EventNameModel` class, have a field to maintain the state of your radio button like the following

```
public class EventNameModel {
    // your other fields
    private boolean isRadioOn;

    public void setIsRadioOn(boolean value){
        this.isRadioOn = value;
    }

    public boolean isRadioOn(){
        return isRadioOn;
    }
}
```

Then adjust you `onBindViewHolder` method like follows

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    EventNameModel movie = eventNameList.get(position);
    holder.eventNameText.setText(movie.getEventName());
    if(movie.isRadioOn()){
        holder.imageViewRadio.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_button_on);
    } else {
        holder.imageViewRadio.setImageResource(R.drawable.radio_button_off);
    }
}
```

Have a method like this in your adapter class to update the position retrieved from your other activity

```
public void updateItemAt(int position){
    EventNameModel movie = eventNameList.get(position);
    movie.setIsRadioOn(true);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Now you can call this method from `onActivityResult` like follows

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            int responseInt =   data.getIntExtra("SUBMIT_DATA",-2);
            if(responseInt>=0){
                mAdapter.updateItemAt(responseInt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. Nice concept.. Thank you so much. Can you please tell me if I would like to select another event then it shows two radio button on, so I would like to reset the the previous one.

Comment: Instead of keeping the state on the EventModel, just keep the last updated position on the adapter class (initially it would be -1). Then check if the last position matches in the `onBindViewHolder` method and apply the background Image.